# Laravel display dynamic menu items on layout template

Tags: laravel-5

I have defined a Category model and table that I'm filling through the backend of my Laravel application. I want to display the categories as menu items.

In my controller, I have something like

```
public function index()
{
    $categories = Category::all();
    return view('layouts.app', ['categories' => $categories]);
}
```

So the idea is that I can loop in the layouts.app template over these categories.

```
 @foreach($categories as $category)
       <li><a href="..." class="user-icon">{{ $category->name}} </a></li>
 @endforeach
```

How can I make sure that my app displays these catagories on all pages (that use the layouts.app template). Normally one could create a route entry but how to do this for the layouts.app template?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new template (e.g. `categories.blade.php`)

```
public function index()
{
    $categories = Category::all();
    return view('categories', ['categories' => $categories]);
}
```

and make sure it extends the layout:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@foreach($categories as $category)
       <li><a href="..." class="user-icon">{{ $category->name}} </a></li>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `view()->composer('*')` which will make the variable available for all your views.

```
view()->composer('*', function ($view) {

    $categories = Category::all();

    return $view->with('categories', $categories);
});
```

You can also change the `*` to specify subgroups such as `foo.bar`.